# fullcalendar with asp.net mvc not showing events fetched from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

i'm Trying to fetch events from my database and populate the fullcalendar with those events. 
the events are not showing . Although when i create events for testing in my controller they are showing

**Controller: events are not showing in this case**

```
        public JsonResult getEvents()
    {
        UserProfile user = getUserProfile();
        List<Calendar> events = db.Calendars.Where(c => c.userID == user.userID).ToList();
        IList<calendarPost> tasksList = new List<calendarPost>();
        foreach (Calendar eve in events)
        {
            tasksList.Add(new calendarPost
            {
                id = eve.recordID,
                title = eve.recordDescription,
                start = ToUnixTimespan(eve.startTime),
                end = ToUnixTimespan(eve.endTime),
                url = "www.google.com"
                //      });
                // }
            });
        }
        return Json(tasksList.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Where If i do this the events are showing :**

```
public JsonResult getEvents()
    {
       UserProfile user = getUserProfile();
       List<Calendar> events = db.Calendars.Where(c => c.userID == user.userID).ToList();
        IList<calendarPost> tasksList = new List<calendarPost>();
  //      foreach (Calendar eve in events)
    //    {
        tasksList.Add(new calendarPost
        {
            id = 5,
            title = "test",
            start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)),
            end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)),
            url = "www.google.com"
            //      });
            // }
        });
        return Json(tasksList.ToArray() , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Yeah and btw both produce the same Json output

```
[{"id":5,"title":"test","start":1336945877,"end":1336949477,"url":"www.google.com","backgroundColor":null}]

[{"id":1,"title":"Testing the Calendar","start":1349384400,"end":1352062800,"url":"www.google.com","backgroundColor":null},{"id":3,"title":"Testing Votes","start":1325748600,"end":1325752200,"url":"www.google.com","backgroundColor":null}]
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint after you assign the events object. Launch the debugger and verify it contains records.

Comment: @RogerHarford it does , the Json output verifies that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a jsonresponse.ashx (handler) file and add following code to that file,

jsonresponse.ashx

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class JsonResponse : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState 
{


public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{

DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 4, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 4, 30);              

String result = String.Empty;

result += "[";

List<long> idList = new List<long>();

List<Calendar> events = db.Calendars.Where(c => c.userID == user.userID).ToList();

foreach (Calendar eve in events)
        {
            result += convertCalendarEventIntoString(eve);
            idList.Add(eve.id);
        }

 if (result.EndsWith(","))
    {
        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
    }

    result += "]";
    //store list of event ids in Session, so that it can be accessed in web methods
    context.Session["idList"] = idList;

    context.Response.Write(result);

}

private String convertCalendarEventIntoString(CalendarEvent cevent)
{
    String allDay = "true";
    if (ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString().Equals(ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString()))
    {

        if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0)
        {
            allDay = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            allDay = "false";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0
            && cevent.end.Hour == 0 && cevent.end.Minute == 0 && cevent.end.Second == 0)
        {
            allDay = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            allDay = "false";
        }
    }
    return    "{" +
              "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
              "title: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "'," +
              "description: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(cevent.description)) + "'," +
              "start:  " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString() + "," +
              "end: " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString() + "," +
              "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
              "description: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "'," +                  
              "url: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.url) + "'" +
              "},";
}

private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{


    long epoch = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
    return epoch;

}
}
```